# How R.id picks up view from XML?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

novice to android but curious to know what is behind R.id.textview . first of all I was going through Documentation and found R is a class which contains a nested class called R.id(). but i couldn't find how an id is used after R.id, So can someone please explain me how this works and how XML file is integrated with Main Activity.

Comment: In an apk you'll find resources.arsc file and it contain the data that R.id.textview will locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android Java framework, `android.R.id.text1` is an identifier of a `TextView` . You can find it in many layouts from the framework (select_dialog_item, select_dialog_singlechoice, simple_dropdown_item_1line, etc.). In Android framework `xml`, it is represented by `@+id/text1`

the xml is integrated with the MainActivity on this line below `onCreate()`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

so, in your MainActivity you just say to Android (hey, just use this layout) and any R.id.... will reference to objects inside that Activity , also you can do this with R.strings   R.layout , etc

`R.layout` calls for an xml layout file.